# What does this lever do near my gas heater?

Tags: hvac, ducts, heater

I am not entirely sure what this big duct work is for.
Its not the exhaust, because im sure the exhaust is the smaller duct on the gar left side (exiting form the enter image description heretop). The big duct as a lever, which i know is to open/close the valve inside the duct.

The question is, what is this duct for?
And should i be keeping the valve opened or closed?

[image]

This is the valve lever:
[image]

Comment: Do you have multiple zones in the home (multiple thermostats)? Does the end of that large round duct connect to the rectangular duct next to the furnace, or does it go behind it to supply some part of the home?

Answer (score 1):

It's a "damper". It can be manually set (open or closed) depending on quantity of air needed.

During the design of the HVAC system, duct sizes are determined based on size and location of rooms they serve...kind of a best guess. Once the system (ducts) are installed, the quantity of air can be adjusted by opening or closing these dampers.

Often we put these dampers on "fresh air" intake ducts. However, they're still used to adjust the amount of outside air. (We usually start at 10% of the total air required.) In residential construction we usually don't have fresh air intake ducts, because of air leakage around doors and windows.

This damper appears to be on the "return air" duct. Keeping the damper "full open", uses the maximum amount of return air.

Comment: What does "return air"  mean? Does this damper adjust the flow of heat into the house?

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar   No, not "heat", but adjusts the amount of air. It could be the amount of "fresh" air or "return" air depending where the duct leads from...

Answer (score 1):

The return duct is located under the heater. Your finger is pointing at a damper on the duct that supplies heated air for some part of the house. It's worth noting that is a very poorly designed and inefficient duct configuration, wrapping a full 180 degrees around one of the other return ducts.

Answer (score 0):

It is a damper to regulate how much air goes through the duct. Parallel to the pipe is fully open, perpendicular to the pipe is mostly closed (there is about a quarter inch gap all around the damper).

Comment: That answer has already been given.